# When changing video currentTime too much, video fails?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm using a user drag event as well as keypresses to change the position in a HTML5 video element and then updating the video time accordingly using:

```
video.currentTime = toTime;
```

and then I am updating a canvas based on the video position by grabbing the video and putting it to the canvas.

Another element is that I actually get the video time from the frame number, i.e:

```
framenumber = 123;
fps = 25;
toTime = 123/25;
```

Problem is, every so often it just *fails*. By fails I mean I lose the video; it just stops working altogether.

Most of the time it works great but sometimes it just fails, and not always at the same point either...

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest adding an onError listener to see if you can see anything that way, and also watching through Fiddler or browser Network tools to see if there's any error coming back from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 answers to my question:

1. Encoding of the video files - basically by controlling keyframes and
   sending the right video to the right browser I was able to solve a
   lot of problems. Using FFMPEG I changed the GOP length.

   `ffmpeg -g <frames>` in my case, where `<frames>` is the amount of frames between GOP points desired.
2. Using [videojs](http://videojs.com/) to serve up the video seemed to solve a lot of problems and made it a smoother an experience.